# Error while starting the weblogic server (12.2.1)?

Tags: weblogic

Could anyone please let me know how to resolve the below issue, I was getting this error when I was trying to start the weblogic server

Current version: 12.2.1
Java: 1.8

```
Version: WebLogic Server 12.2.1.0.0 Tue Oct  6 10:05:47 PDT 2015 1721936
Jan 21, 2016 4:24:01 PM IST Critical WebLogicServer BEA-000386 Server subsystem failed. Reason: A MultiException has 5 exceptions.  They are:
1. weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessImpl$ParseException: [Management:141266]Parsing failure in config.xml: weblogic.management.ManagementRuntimeException: Could not create the JMS descriptor. Error encountered in file: /home/oracle/wls_domains/domains/soa_qa_domain/config/jms/bampersistencejmsmodule-jms.xml.
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessImpl
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessService
4. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.t3.srvr.FinalThreadLocalService errors were found
5. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.t3.srvr.FinalThreadLocalService

A MultiException has 5 exceptions.  They are:
1. weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessImpl$ParseException: [Management:141266]Parsing failure in config.xml: weblogic.management.ManagementRuntimeException: Could not create the JMS descriptor. Error encountered in file: /home/oracle/wls_domains/domains/soa_qa_domain/config/jms/bampersistencejmsmodule-jms.xml.
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessImpl
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessService
4. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.t3.srvr.FinalThreadLocalService errors were found
5. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.t3.srvr.FinalThreadLocalService

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Collector.throwIfErrors(Collector.java:89)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:249)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:211)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:234)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:211)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:234)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused By: weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessImpl$ParseException: [Management:141266]Parsing failure in config.xml: weblogic.management.ManagementRuntimeException: Could not create the JMS descriptor. Error encountered in file: /home/oracle/wls_domains/domains/soa_qa_domain/config/jms/bampersistencejmsmodule-jms.xml.
        at weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessImpl.getParseFailureException(RuntimeAccessImpl.java:394)
        at weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessImpl.convertXmlException(RuntimeAccessImpl.java:358)
        at weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessImpl.parseNewStyleConfig(RuntimeAccessImpl.java:297)
        at weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessImpl.<init>(RuntimeAccessImpl.java:127)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1350)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:271)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:365)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:767)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getUnqualifiedService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:774)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.IterableProviderImpl.get(IterableProviderImpl.java:111)
        at weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessService.start(RuntimeAccessService.java:64)
        at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:76)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1262)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:332)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:374)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:211)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:234)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:211)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:234)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:211)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:234)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused By: weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorValidateException: The following failures occurred:
-- Unresolved reference to BamPersistenceErrorQueue_auto_1 by /UniformDistributedQueues[dist_BamPersistenceQueue_auto]/DeliveryFailureParams/ErrorDestination
```

Comment: hey Bharat, did you got  fix ... any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

We have encountered a similar issue, WebLogic has deleted the `config.xml` for some reason, and that caused the issue. Fortunately there is a backup `config.xml` file under `%DOMAIN_DIR%\servers\domain_bak\config_prev`, which you can copy. This should fix the issue.